# Java Spring Boot applcation with bizarre compilation error not finding Java classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I suddenly started receiving errors when trying to run any maven command on my Spring Boot Java Project.

It seems that it´s not finding any Java class anymore, even java being in the PATH as below:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)

$ which java
/c/Program Files/OpenJDK/openjdk-8u312-b07/bin/java
```

When I run:
`$ mvn clean package`

I get some bizarre errors such as:

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ APP_NAME ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 55 source files to C:\Users\francisco.souza\Projetos\Java\2022\APP_NAME\target\classes


The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.isAccessible(Resolve.java:299)

...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/francisco.souza/Projetos/Java/2022/APP_NAME/src/main/java/br/com/dark/icc/ura/app/steps/StepDesliga.java:[33,13] cannot access Map
  class file for Map not found
[ERROR] /C:/Users/francisco.souza/Projetos/Java/2022/APP_NAME/src/main/java/br/com/dark/icc/ura/app/steps/StepDesliga.java:[45,64] incompatible types: Map cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>
[ERROR] /C:/Users/francisco.souza/Projetos/Java/2022/APP_NAME/src/main/java/br/com/dark/icc/ura/app/steps/StepDesliga.java:[58,48] cannot access List
  class file for List not found
```

As you can see its not finding classes like List, Map, String, etc...

Any ideas how to solve this? I had never seen something like this before.

The system is Windows 10

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: You probably forgot the `import java.util.List` and now it tries to load a regular class instead of the one from the JDK.

Comment: Which IDE you use?

Comment: @M.Deinum no, actually the import is there, that´s not the problem, unfortunately, it´s a big project that was working until two days ago.

Comment: @Nemanja It´s IntelliJ, but if I run on the maven command on the command line I get the same result.

Comment: Try to increase stack size for compiler process (in Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | User-local build process VM options (overrides Shared options):) to e.g. -Xss4m

Comment: Outofresources? Does it work on another system?

Comment: @tgdavies no, it did solve my problem, I tried it here. No good.

Comment: Then document what you've tried from the answers to that question in your question. Eliminating possibilities will help people help you.